# Is there any way to add visa card payment support to Paypal android API MPL?

Tags: android, paypal, e-commerce

Is there any way to add credit card payment support to an android application that uses Paypal android library MPL? The default activity that comes with the library doesn't contain any method to pay using credit cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there isn't.
Paypal gives other options, such as the MECL for such a use.
See more details [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-express-checkout-library)

Comment: That links states: "The Mobile Express Checkout Library for iOS and Android have been discontinued."

Comment: Hi newbies finding out the answer to this question refer to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964851/card-payment-using-paypal-android/32176172#32176172