# Card payment Using PayPal android

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway

Can we implement Paypal with a card payment. e.g. Somebody doesn't have paypal account so he/she can pay using debit or credit card. Is there any way to implement paypal with card. 
Please help.

Comment: Using a Sandbox, you can create a demo payment account. have a look at these links http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide/test_user_setup.html

http://www.webassist.com/support/documentation/how-tos/paypal_sandbox.php

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ug_sandbox#accounts

Comment: paypal documentation cover all these information.

Comment: @minhaz I used that code but its giving me 503 error.

Comment: AFAIK using Paypal Android SDK user can pay just with his/her Paypal account, not with credit card.

Comment: @rciovati, using Sandbox account you can create a virtual credit card, which is actually a number( like credit cart number ) and other of credit card type  information like expiry date, cvv number. So using this information you can test your payment part.

Comment: @Lucifer: correct but the users can't pay directly with credit card without having Paypal account.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I know I am very late to answer this question but surely folks implementing Paypal in their app will get benefit from this!
Android SDK for Paypal does not support Card Payment but yes "Rest API sdk for Paypal" has the capability. Include this in your build.gradle:               compile 'com.paypal.sdk:rest-api-sdk:1.2.5'

And then try the following method:

```
public static final String  CLIENT_ID = "AQkquBDf1zctJOWGKWUEtKXm6qVhueUEMvXO_-MCI4DQQ4-LWvkDLIN2fGsd";
public static final String  CLIENT_SECRET = "EL1tVxAjhT7cJimnz5-Nsx9k2reTKSVfErNQF-CmrwJgxRtylkGTKlU4RvrX";

/**
     * @method getAccessToken is used to get AccessToken for performing authorised transcations
     * @param clientId credential that we get when we register our application on https://developer.paypal.com/
     * @param clientSecret credential that we get when we register our application on https://developer.paypal.com/
     * @return String accessToken
     */
    public static final String getAccessToken(String clientId, String clientSecret){
        Log.i(TAG,"GetAccessToken called");
        String accessToken = "";
        long expiresIn;

        try {
            OAuthTokenCredential oAuthTokenCredential = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientId, clientSecret, getSdKConfig());
            expiresIn = oAuthTokenCredential.expiresIn();
            accessToken = oAuthTokenCredential.getAccessToken();
             Log.i(TAG, "AccessToken: "+accessToken);
        } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return accessToken;
    }

 /**
         * @method makeDirectPayment is used for making direct payment via credit cards. Customers who don't have paypal account can pay via this method.
         * @return String with Payment Id and Payment status
         */
        public static final String makeDirectPayment(){

            String accessToken = getAccessToken(Constants.CLIENT_ID, Constants.CLIENT_SECRET);
            String message = "";
            if (accessToken != null && !accessToken.equals("")){
                APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
                apiContext.setConfigurationMap(getSdKConfig());

                CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard();
                creditCard.setType("visa");
                creditCard.setNumber("4446283280247004");
                creditCard.setExpireMonth(11);
                creditCard.setExpireYear(2019);
                creditCard.setFirstName("Test");
                creditCard.setLastName("Shopper");

                FundingInstrument fundingInstrument = new FundingInstrument();
                fundingInstrument.setCreditCard(creditCard);

                List<FundingInstrument> fundingInstrumentList = new ArrayList<>();
                fundingInstrumentList.add(fundingInstrument);

                Payer payer = new Payer();
                payer.setFundingInstruments(fundingInstrumentList);
                payer.setPaymentMethod("credit_card");

                Amount amount = new Amount();
                amount.setCurrency("EUR");
                amount.setTotal("50");

                Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
                transaction.setDescription("Creating Direct Payment with Credit Card");
                transaction.setAmount(amount);

                List<Transaction> transactionList = new ArrayList<>();
                transactionList.add(transaction);

                Payment payment = new Payment();
                payment.setIntent("sale");
                payment.setTransactions(transactionList);
                payment.setPayer(payer);

                try {
                    Payment createdPayment = payment.create(apiContext);

                    if (createdPayment != null){
                        Log.i(TAG,"Payment object: "+createdPayment.toJSON());
                        message = "Payment Id: " + createdPayment.getId() + " Payment status: "+createdPayment.getState();
                        Log.i(TAG, message);
                    }
                } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return message;
        }
```

Note for simplicity I have used everything static but you can maintain your own UI to get no of items, its pricing, credit card details from user.